# How to work with other person on one branch in Git?

Tags: git

I'm working on some feature with my co-worker. We created topic-branch. And everything is ok when we only merge everything - our branch on server with local copies and master to keep our branch up to date. But it is not ideal workflow.

Could anyone point me a better solution?

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about what makes the workflow not ideal? I'm not sure how to start answering this.

Comment: For,example, I would like sometimes rebase master (to have our commits on top), or squash some commits.

Comment: If you modify commits that your co-worker has, you're going to make a mess for your co-worker unless the two of you are very careful in how you handle it. You should each be on separate branches if you're going to rebase/squash. Don't modify `master`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to work with your co-worker without having to use the main repository as middle hand. I'd add the other persons repository as a remote and create a branch that is tracking his topic-branch. The other person can then do the same, but set your local topic-branch as his upstream branch.

Something like

1. git remote add coworker file:////coworkersComputer/path/to/repo
2. git fetch coworker
3. git checkout --track coworker/topic-branch

Here you can pull changes from your coworker. If you want to rebase stuff you can always create local branches and rebase them onto topic-branch.

Your coworker must set up your computer in similar fashion:

1. git remote add yourRepo file:////..
2. git fetch yourRepo
3. git branch --set-upstream topic-branch yourRepo/topic-branch

A nice thing with this is that you can work in complete isolation without causing any troubles to other coworkers. You have already setup each other as remotes so 1. is only needed one time. 2 and 3. is only needed when you want to setup a new topic to work on.

Comment: Let's say we are in a LAN, so my coworker has the 192.168.1.33,
What would be the command to add his repo?
git remote add coworker 192.168.1.33:/coworkersComputer/path/to/repo

?

Comment: git remote add coworker file:////192.168.1.33/path/to/repo, assuming your coworker has shared his repo over the LAN

Answer (score 1):

This is how I like to do it. Each of you should work on your own branch. When integrating, checkout the master branch and pull from each of your branches (where you will have added, committed and pulled the relevant changes you want to get to production).

A continuous integration server like Integrity ([www.integrityapp.com](http://www.integrityapp.com/)) should help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are doing a `git pull` from the server, when really what you want is `git fetch`. The problem is that `git pull` automatically merges your local branch with the remote branch that it is tracking, but `git fetch` does not.

The solution would be to only use `git fetch`, and then either `git merge origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master` (replace `master` with the actual branch name) afterward, depending on what you want the history to look like.